# Hibernate: how to look for objects in a Set

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to figure out what the best way to write the HQL statement for the following scenario is:

I have a class Book which one of its properties is of the type Set{Author} (actually meant to type inequality signs here). The class Author has properties such as id, name, etc.

Now my DAO method gets "Set **authors**" as a parameter. For this method I want to write an HQL query so I could get all the Books that at least one of their Authors is found in **authors**.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Pay attention that both the Set property in the class Book and the Set parameter that is being passed on to the method may include multiple Authors.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Had I had only one author per Book, I could have done something like:

```
FROM Book as book WHERE book.author IN (:authors)
```

However this does not work when each Book has a Set of Authors.

Comment: So you have a many-to-many relationship between Book and Author?

Comment: Yes, it's a many-to-many relationship between Book and Author.

Comment: Your life would be easier if you used an association table between them, ie `create table book_author (book_id int, author_id int);` that had one-to-many with both book and author and remove the direct relationship between book and author. Then the query would be simple, as would probably other challenges.

Comment: I do not understand why you are saying this. First, I do have that association table between Book and Author. Second, I think using an association table is my only option when I use many-to-many. Third, I do not understand how the table model would make the query easier? HQL queries refer to the class model, not to the table model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
select distinct b from Book b join b.authors a where a in (:authors)
```

Note that if you need `join fetch`, it should be specified separately:

```
select distinct b from Book b join b.authors a left join fetch b.authors 
where a in (:authors)
```

Comment: Thank you. It's a combination of Tristan's idea to go through every author in the Set property by

    "book.authors author where author"
    
(I did not know I could do this!), with what I mentioned in my comment, about using

    "WHERE author IN (:authors)"
    
* The only problem I still see is, that the returned Books, contain in their "authors" property only those authors that matched with the "authors" parameter... How do I make it to return the relevant Books in such a way that their authors property will contain their full set of Authors as it appears in the DB?

Comment: @rapt: Cannot reproduce your problem, works fine for me (Hibernate 3.6.2). Also note the `distinct` keyword.

Comment: That's really weird. I don't understand how it works for you. I am trying "SELECT DISTINCT b FROM Book as b LEFT JOIN FETCH b.authors author WHERE author IN (:authors) ORDER BY b.id DESC". When I think about it, you are supposed to see the same problem. Since it says: join a row from Book, with rows from Author (that point to that row in Book) AND (the WHERE clause) also match an Author in the parameter "authors". So rows in Author that point to that row in Book but do NOT match any Author in that parameter should not be joined to that row in Book, hence not appear in the output. Any ideas???

Comment: Thanks. It works now with your 2nd suggestion. Your 1st suggestion: I can see why it works, but it's more due to the way hibernate does lazy fetching. The actual hql says to return (within each authors property) only authors that are in the parameter, but because it's lazy fetching, the authors property remains empty until the query ends, then when it is being somehow fetched (before the end of session), hibernate doesn't care what has not been fetched, and simply fetches the whole collection from DB. So it does do what I needed but it's not what you expect from the actual statement.

Comment: Your 2nd suggestion: I can see why it works, but it's kind of convoluted, calling b.authors twice in the same statement? I would suggest doing something like this, which is more natural in my eyes: "SELECT b FROM Book as b LEFT JOIN FETCH b.authors WHERE b.id = SOME (SELECT DISTINCT b.id FROM Book as b JOIN b.authors a WHERE a IN (:authors)) ORDER BY b.id DESC"

Answer (score 0):

is there a particular reason why you don't want to use Hibernate's Criteria to do this?

```
Set<Author> authors = [ your set of Author Objects ]
Criteria crit = createCriteria(Book.class)
                .add( Restrictions.in( "author", authors ) );

List<Book> books = crit.list();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to make one hql query by author passed as a parameter.

For each author, the HQL will look like :

```
from Book as book 
join book.authors author 
where author = < one_of_my_author_passed_as_parameter >
```

And then, you add the result of each query to the main result list.

Comment: This query is wrong for at least two reasons. 1. You compare entity instead of scalar. 2. He is asking completely different question. Hint: `at least` is very different from `less than`

Comment: 1. Well, it's a short way to write it, because I don't know what is the natural key for "Author" ("name, etc...") 2. What do u mean ? Maybe you read the query, and not what is before and after ? 3. Why don't u give a better answer if you know it ?

Comment: Please clarify your answer. Note that `book.authors` is a set and you can't compare it. And I would not use '<>' as delimiters in HQL query. In it's current form your answer is very confusing.